# Are basic armor mods compatible with their higher tiers?

Tags: fallout-4

For instance, "Leather left leg with studded leather".

Can I remove the studded leather and apply it to a heavy leather left leg piece?

Comment: Trying would be faster. Or you just want someone else to try?

Comment: @Sinatr: With this reasoning, the whole fallout wiki would be obsolete, because someone had to try it first before he had information he could share with others. This thread will also be found over google for anyone else having this question and looking it up.

Comment: You are right, but you need like 3 min to try, which is slightly faster to get answer compared to 4 hours waiting for an expert. Why don't you try and post the answer yourself? I can't post the answer, because I don't remember (haven't played fallout 4 for a long time), but afair I figured it out myself, so it was pretty obvious ;)

Comment: @Sinatr Not if I'm not at a high level in my current playthrough and don't have access to heavy items yet, but still considering buying low-gear with modifications on them, when I see some at some merchants, so that I will later be able to "un-mod" and use the mod on my newly found heavy gear. Don't see the 3min work here, otherwise I could do it and post an answer myself.

Comment: Looking at *classes* for armor mods [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_armor_mods) I'd conclude what as long as armor class is the same the mods can be reused.

Comment: But your low level mods are completely dwarfed by the high level ones.  There's no point to keep your low level stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_armor_mods#Notes):

> you can apply mods made for lesser armor pieces to more advanced pieces of the same material type

So the answer is: yes.